# dynamic_cast on shared_ptr object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast, derived

I want to check which object I'm dealing with, because I want to replace them, so I made a cast.

```
void Promote(vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {

    auto it = std::find_if(sourceEmployee.begin(), sourceEmployee.end(),
        [&sourceEmployee, id](const auto &obj) { return obj->getID() == id; });

    if (it != sourceEmployee.end()) {

        // I want to return true whether I'm dealing with "Intern" class object
        if (auto w = dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<Intern>>(it->get())) { // ERROR
            auto tmp0 = std::move(*it);
            *it = std::make_shared<Worker>(*tmp0);
        }
```

I'm getting an error (target is not pointer or reference) on this line:

```
if (auto w = dynamic_cast<std::shared_ptr<Intern>>(it->get()))
```

EDIT: I'm stupid. Just use `auto w = dynamic_cast<Intern*>(it->get())`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dynamic_cast<Intern*>`? Why do you want to cast to a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Yess, I just figured it out.. ;D

Comment: You also have [std::dynamic_pointer_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) and friends.

Comment: As @super points out; there's `dynamic_pointer_cast` for this.